# The XY problem and multiple answers

Tags: discussion, multiple-answers

When dealing with the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), sometimes the original question is of some interest - for instance, it might indicate some conceptual mistake by the OP that should be corrected, even it is unrelated to the actual answer. In such cases, is it a good idea to post two separate answers?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698764/select-on-a-cross-join-returning-wrong-results) roughly fits the scenario above. The original answer was an educated guess on the cause of the immediate problem. After some discussion, the OP clarified the requirements, making it possible to suggest more significant improvements which were only loosely related to the initial issue. In that occasion, I ended up editing the original answer rather than adding a second one.)

Comment: Or one answer encompassing both points. You only really need to have multiple answers if they are opposing (such as if you later changed your mind)

Comment: Don't for the love of all thats holy use "Edit: such and such" though. Use section headers to make a single cohesive answer